# Total all time stored in an array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array variable, I store all the time in this array.
I want to total all the stored value in my array.
I tried using a for loop but it can't read the time format.

I'm using CakePHP

In my usercontroller:

```
$this->set('project_time',$sele_lang['time']);
```

I used that code to get the estimated time for each project.
i don't have any problem with this.

then in my php to get set time
i created a variable and array to stor the time.

$target_time and $stored_time=array()

```
if(i have two projects) //i assume that i have two project
for($i = 0; $i < count($lang_val); $i++)
{
    $target_time = $project_time; // this will get the estimated time
    $stored_time[] = $target_time; //this will store the time in array.

    $tempo = date("H:i:s", strtotime($stored_time[$i])); //this will get the first array value.

}
```

I'm stacked here.

I don't know if there's something a function that can sum all the time stored in my array.
or 
I'm thinking that if i stored the first value to a temp file then add the temp value to a the second value of the array that would give me the result i want but it a time based i only tried that to a integer.

thanks for advance. sorry for the lack of information in my first post.

Comment: This code piece does no make sense, please show full code.

Comment: Dude.... this is messed up...

Comment: `$a = 1; $b = $a; $c = $b; $d = $c;`. It makes absolutely no sense. You don't use the array at all and you always refer to the same variables. Perhaps look at [`array_reduce`](http://www.php.net/array_reduce).

Comment: You code doesn't make sense

Comment: it goes something like this

my array stored value just like this:

array[1] = 00:15:00
array[2] = 00:15:00

then how can i total that all so it will give me an answer of 00:30:00

i tried a for loop but it no luck.

Comment: @RhyManlangit The loop you posted has nothing to do with this at all - is this really your try?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [For-each over an array in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? Your code doesn't make sense, this is my best interpretation. (And it's a bad way of doing it. We can merge the second loop in the first one.

```
for($i=0;$i<count($lang_val);$i++){
  $target_time = $project_time;
  $stored_time[] = $target_time; //Assuming this is a timestamp
}

$intTotalTime = 0;
foreach($stored_time as $intTimeStamp) {
  $intTotalTime += $intTimeStamp;
}
echo "Total Time: ". date("H:i:s", strtotime($intTotalTime));
```

Comment: or simply `$intTotalTime = count($lang_val) * $project_time;`. That said, these are timestamps - you'd end up hitting an integer overflow if there's too many values. Use `bcadd`.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you like to get the sum of timestamps? The result would be a very odd number.

I assume the $lang_val is an array with timestamps.

```
$new = array();
foreach( $lang_val as $entry ) {
    $new[] = strtotime( $entry );
}

// Debugging
var_dump( $new );
// Actual value
var_dump( array_sum($new) );
```

Or

```
$total = 0;
foreach( $lang_val as $entry ) {
    $total += strtotime( $entry );
}
```

After your comment:

```
$data = array(
    '00:15:00',
    '01:05:05',
    '10:00:15'
);

$total = 0;
foreach( $data as $timestamp ) {
    // Get values or set default if not present.
    list( $hours, $minutes, $seconds ) = explode( ':', $data ) + array(
            0 => 0,
            1 => 0,
            2 => 0
    );

    // Convert to seconds
    $hours = $hours * 3600;
    $minutes = $minutes * 60;

    $total += $hours + $minutes + $seconds; 
}

var_dump( $total );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`array_reduce`](http://www.php.net/array_reduce) and [`strtotime`](http://www.php.net/strtotime):

```
<?php

$array = array('00:10:15', '02:00:00', '05:30:00');

// Get total amount of seconds
$seconds = array_reduce($array, function($carry, $timestamp) {
        return $carry + strtotime('1970-01-01 ' . $timestamp);
}, 0);

// Get hours
$hours = floor($seconds/ 3600);
$seconds -= $hours * 3600;

// Get minutes
$minutes = floor($seconds/ 60);
$seconds -= $minutes * 60;

// Convert to timestamp
$timestamp = sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', $hours, $minutes, $seconds);

var_dump($timestamp); //string(8) "07:40:15"
```

[**DEMO**](https://eval.in/153301)